# Is it possible to have predefined schemes for Windows Application's positions and sizes?

Tags: windows, graphics, video-streaming

Is it possible to have predefined schemes for Windows Application's positions and sizes?

The main idea is not having to move and resize windows every time I need to change the type of work (coding / streaming).

I searched a bit but didn't find any clear solution.

Thanks

Comment: Do multiple desktops help? You could switch them with [Win] + [Tab]

Comment: It's something, but when I restart the computer it doesn't keep the same.

Answer (score 0):

So far, the best solution I found was to use an "Elgato - Dock Station".

Comment: Isn't it a hardware?

Comment: Yes, the idea behind is to automate the windows resizing and positions, etc...